querying from json rolling data files
I have a series of json files. Each file has the information for the last 30 days. Within each file, the data is broken down by date. So for example,

File_Mar31 has data for Mar 1 - Mar 30 (broken down by day within each file)

File_Apr1 has data for Mar 2 - Mar 31, etc.

Etc.


The data for any data will be repeated in 30 files. So I can use the last file in teh series with data for that OR I can use any file with that data also.
Essentially I want to query these files in PowerBI providing a time range (Last 7 days, Last 30 days, Last 60 days, etc.)
Being a newbie to this, what is the best way to store this data? This is definitely not in the realm of big data. But I would like some advice on how best to store and query these files. Should this be in a time series database? Should I just query the raw files? Any suggestion is appreciated!
Thanks
Jake.

Since this is not a huge dataset, I ended up just collapsing all the individual files into a single file while eliminating duplicates. After that for daily deltas, I merge the new file with the existing file. This adds any new nodes into the single json file. So my existing PBI report also did not have to change. It was adequate for my needs.
